# S3c2440(ARM9) spi_read_write Flash Memory

Tags: embedded, spi, arm9

I am working on SPI communication.Trying to communicate SST25VF032B(32 MB microchip SPI Flash).
When I am reading the Manufacturer Id it shows MF_ID =>4A25BF 
but originally it is MF_ID =>BF254A. I am getting it simply reverse, means first bite in 3rd and 3rd byte in first.

What could be the possible reason for that?
My SPI Init function is here:

```
//Enable clock control register CLKCON 18 Bit enables SPI  
CLKCON |= (0x01 << 18);//0x40000;  
printk("s3c2440_clkcon=%08ld\n",CLKCON);
//Enable GPG2 Corresponding NSS port
GPGCON =0x1011;//010000 00 01 00 01
printk("s3c2440_GPGCON=%08ld\n",GPGCON);
SPNSS0_ENABLE(); 
//Enable GPE 11,12,13,Corresponding MISO0,MOSI0,SCK0 = 11 0x0000FC00
GPECON &= ~((3 << 22) | (3 << 24) | (3 << 26));  
GPECON |=  ((2 << 22) | (2 << 24) | (2 << 26));  
//GPEUP Set; all disable  
GPGUP &= ~(0x07 << 2);    
GPEUP |=  (0x07 << 11);
//SPI Register section
//SPI Prescaler register settings,  
//Baud Rate=PCLK/2/(Prescaler value+1)  
SPPRE0 = 0x18;       //freq = 1M 
printk("SPPRE0=%02X\n",SPPRE0);  

//polling,en-sck,master,low,format A,nomal = 0 | TAGD = 1  
SPCON0 = (0<<5)|(1<<4)|(1<<3)|(0<<2)|(0<<1)|(0<<0);  
printk("SPCON1=%02ld\n",SPCON0);  

//Multi-host error detection is enabled 
SPPIN0 = (0 << 2) | (1 << 1) | (0 << 0);  
printk("SPPIN1=%02X\n",SPPIN0);  

//Initialization procedure
SPTDAT0 = 0xff;
```

My spi_read_write function as follows:

```
static char spi_read_write (unsigned char outb) 
{
   // Write and Read a byte on SPI interface.  

   int j = 0;  
   unsigned char inb;
   SPTDAT0 = outb;  
   while(!SPI_TXRX_READY) for(j = 0; j < 0xFF; j++);  
   SPTDAT0 = outb;
   //SPTDAT0 = 0xff;  
   while(!SPI_TXRX_READY) for(j = 0; j < 0xFF; j++);   
   inb = SPRDAT0; 
   return (inb);   
}
```

My Calling function is:

```
   MEM_1_CS(0);
   spi_read_write(0x9F);
   m1 = spi_read_write(0x00);
   m2 = spi_read_write(0x00);
   m3 = spi_read_write(0x00);
   MEM_1_CS(1); 
   printk("\n\rMF_ID =>%02X-%02X-%02X",m1,m2,m3);
```

Please guide me what to do?
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There's no apparent problem with the SPI function.
The problem is with your printing function.
Arm is `little endian` processor. it keeps the bytes reversed in memory.
You need to print it reverse order and you'll be fine.

Comment: My spi_read_write function is unsigned char & I keep the return value in three different variable. so, it should print first value first which return from spi_read_write function. Suppose, my function return integer and I am getting 0x11223344 insted of 0x44332211 that can be explained by `little endian` or `big endian`.

Comment: I used previous controller that is Cortex-M3. I got MF_ID =>BF254A there.My calling function is same as previous, only `spi_read_write` and `spi_init` function are different. But, here I am getting MF_ID =>4A25BF. I mean sequence of command are same as previous then why I am getting it in reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

I was banging my head on this from last couple of days and finally I find the solution. All I needed to change my  `spi_read_write` function as follows.

```
static char spi_read_write (unsigned char outb) 
{
   int j = 0;  
   unsigned char inb;   
   while(!SPI_TXRX_READY) for(j = 0; j < 0xFF; j++); 
   SPTDAT0 = outb;   
   while(!SPI_TXRX_READY) for(j = 0; j < 0xFF; j++);   
   inb = SPRDAT0;
   return (inb);       
}
```

**CHANGES MADE:**

First of all we have to check whether the  `SPI_TXRX_READY` then fill the register with the value `SPTDAT0 = outb;`.

Thanks all for your kind support.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. This couldn't cause you're bytes read the other way around.

Comment: but in datasheet says you have to fill `SPTDAT0 = 0xff;` before reading the SPI Register. Anyway thanks for your comment. There is also dummy read concept what is that?