# SPI Driver for uC s3c2451 to configure HSSPI->SPI Channel 0?

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module, spi, arm9

I have started a threat to read/write SPI flash memory for s3c2440 Microcontroller. All register setting are done properly and flash memory read/write functionality working perfectly.

[S3c2440(ARM9) spi_read_write Flash Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136634/s3c2440arm9-spi-read-write-flash-memory/30138124#30138124)

Now, I want to do the same thing with "S3C2451 16/32-Bit RISC Microprocessor"
Then what will be the register configuration for "S3C2451" to achieve the same?

I have studied and compared both the datasheet "S3C2440A" and "S3C2451" and found that so many register are different. I have also notice that in datasheet  says "S3C2440A" is "32-BIT CMOS MICROCONTROLLER" and "S3C2451
" is "16/32-Bit RISC Microprocessor". So, Is it not the same architecture wise?

So, please guide me to achieve the same.

**UPDATE**

I got a link of nearly similar code of s3c6410. But at a glance I am not able
to understand what will be the minimum register configuration for
configuring SPI channel 0 with 5 MHz clock output.

http://read.pudn.com/downloads131/sourcecode/embed/558985/Components/con...

I want to configure it for s3c2451 Processor. Please guide me .....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody is there who have worked on the SPI device driver on S3c2451?

Comment: There is `spi-s3c24xx.c` driver in the Linux kernel. I guess it will work in minimal configuration with different chips. However, you may check datasheet to be sure what should be done to achieve the driver working.

Comment: If the SPI IP is similar to what you have in s3c6410, you may refer to `spi-s3c64xx.c`.